# Prove that $L(C_x)=L(C_y)$ when $I(C_x)=I(C_y)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

[this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=32c4d424-9b8c-11e6-818c-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1477493893_2de85ffc3453abfdf9cbed979c343b16) **Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces** by *Pratulananda Das*

**Definition:** $y ∈ X$ is called an $I$-limit point of $x$ if there exists a set $M = \{m_1 < m_2 < m_3 < ···\} ⊂ \mathbb N$ such that $M \not∈ I$ and
$\lim_{k→∞} x_{m_k} = y$

Theorem $4.$ The case for the $I$-limit points. The thing I cannot prove it. Here is my attempt:

$z\in L(C_x)$. Let $U$ be a nbd of $z\ $. Then  $x_{m_k}\in U \forall k\ge n_0$ Now I want to show that $z\in L(C_y)$ as well. For this we have to prove that for some $m_0\in \mathbb N$ $y_{m_k}\in U\forall k\ge m_0$. If possible let this does not hold i.e. for every $n,\exists n_1`\ge n$ s.t $y_{n_k}\notin U$

I believe that after this step somehow I should use the fact that $L(C_x)\subset I(C_x)$  but cannot decide how. Please just give me some hints as to how to begin the next step, hopefully I can manage the rest. Thank you.

Comment: It is kind of difficult to give a hint how to prove a result which does not hold. But if you wish to try the proof yourself, then do not look at the answer below. Just notice that Theorem 4 with the condition $$\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}\notin\mathcal I$$ (as stated in the paper) does not hold. Try to replace this with
$$\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}\in\mathcal I$$
and then try whether you can prove this result.

Comment: Also if the ideal is not a P-ideal is not a P-ideal, then $\mathcal I$-limit points and $\mathcal I$-cluster points can be quite different. So it seems unlikely to me that you can infer something about the sets $\mathcal I$-limit points from equality of the $\mathcal I$-cluster points. (But perhaps I am missing something and my intuition fails me on this.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Sorry , I should have corrected the statement myself because when I wrote the proof for $I$-cluster points I had realized that $\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\neq y_n\}\notin I$  is not helping the proof, $\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\neq y_n\}\in I$ is what made sense in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this theorem is formulated in the linked paper is definitely incorrect. Here is the exact quote, to stress the incorrect part I will put it as a centered formula.

> **Theorem 4. (incorrect version)** Let $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are two sequences in $X$ such that $$\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}\notin\mathcal I$$ then $\mathcal I(C_x)=\mathcal I(C_y)$ and $\mathcal I(L_x)=\mathcal I(L_y)$.

(Here $\mathcal I(C_x)$ denotes the set of $\mathcal I$-cluster points of the sequence $x$ and $\mathcal I(L_x)$ is the set if $\mathcal I$-limit points.)

To find a counterexample, simply take $x$ and $y$ as two different constant sequences.

Looking at the proof, the author probably intended to write this:

> **Theorem 4. (corrected version)** Let $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are two sequences in $X$ such that $$\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}\in\mathcal I$$ then $\mathcal I(C_x)=\mathcal I(C_y)$ and $\mathcal I(L_x)=\mathcal I(L_y)$.

The intuition is that if we change values of some sequence on a "small set" (set from ideal), then this does not influence $\mathcal I$-limits and other similar notions which basically say how sequence behaves "on large sets" or "modulo this ideal".

After this correction the proof of $\mathcal I(C_x)=\mathcal I(C_y)$ from the paper works.

About limit points: Let $\mathcal F$ be a dual filter of the ideal $\mathcal I$. Let $a$ be a limit point of $x$, i.e. there exists a set $M\in \mathcal F$ such that the subsequence $x|_M$ converges to $a$ in the usual sense. Since
$$A=\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}\in\mathcal I$$
we get that $M'=M\setminus A\in\mathcal F$. For this set we have that $y|_{M'}=x|_{M'}$. This implies that $y_{M'}$ is a subsequence of $x|_M$ and therefor it also converges to $a$. Thus $a$ is $\mathcal I$-limit point of the sequence $y$.

Comment: $A=\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\neq y_n\}$ then $M'=M\cap A^c=M\backslash A \in \mathcal F.$ And for that $n\in M'$ we have $x_n=y_n.$ Is it? So $M'=M\backslash A$ and not $M\backslash B.$ $B$ is not defined here.

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. Indeed I should have written the same letter in both spaces (either both $A$'s or both $B$'s), I did not check my answer carefully enough after writing it. (A bit of irony, considering that my post is critical to a mistake made in the statement in the linked paper.) And the argument why $M'$ belongs to the filter $\mathcal F$ is exactly the argument you wrote in your comment. (And as you noticed, then we have $x_n=y_n$ for $M'$, so it is clear that it converges to the same limit.)